# Calculating time difference on datetime object in Entity Framework giving error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime

I am trying to calculate time difference between 2 date and want to get day name of my date.

For Ex.: 4/7/2016

- Day: Monday

Here is my class:

```
public class Attendance
{
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDateTime { get; set; }
      public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

When I am trying to do this:

```
 var query = (from t in context.Attendance
              select new 
              {
                 timeDiff=t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).TotalHours,
                 Day=System.StartDateTime.ToString("dddd");
              }).tolist();
```

Error

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan
>   Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression

I don't want to do like below:

```
 var query = (from t in context.Attendance.toList().
                  select new 
                  {
                     timeDiff=t.EndDateTime.Value.Subtract(t.StartDateTime.Value).TotalHours,
                     Day=System.StartDateTime.ToString("dddd");
                  }).tolist();
```

I have `Datetime` in format like this stored in my tables and so I want expected output like below shown in difference field:

```
startDatetime              Enddatetime                Difference
----------------------------------------------------------------
2016-06-29 15:52:32.360    2016-06-29 15:52:36.970    00:00:04
2016-06-29 15:53:32.360    2016-06-29 15:55:36.970    00:2:00
2016-06-29 15:53:32.360    2016-06-29 16:55:36.970    01:02:00
```

Comment: You cannot use the difference calculation inside linq. Create a variable outside the query and then use it.

Comment: @FlorianSchaal:My Both StartDateTime and EndDateTime are table fields

Comment: it's the Subtract that can't be used inside linq. Perform the subtraction outside linq.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use .NET framework specific methods in EF queries unless there's a canonical function defined for them. However there are, for your specific query:

Try:

```
 var query = (from t in context.Attendance
                  select new 
                  {                        
                     TimeDiff=SqlFunctions.DateDiff("hour",t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime),
                     Day=SqlFunctions.DateName("weekday", t.StartDateTime);
                  }).ToList();
```

#### Update

To reflect the changes in the wanted output in your question:

```
 var query = (from t in context.Attendance
                  select new 
                  {                        
                     StartDate = t.StartDateTime,
                     EndDate = t.EndDateTime,       
                     TimeDiff=SqlFunctions.DateDiff("second",t.StartDateTime, t.EndDateTime),
                  }).ToList();
```

And then your can use something like:

```
foreach(var q in query)
{
  Console.Write($"{q.StartDate:d} {q.EndDate:d} {TimeSpan.FromSeconds(q.TimeDiff):c}");
}
```

Comment: The [`EntityFunctions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.entityfunctions(v=vs.113).aspx) class was obsoleted quite some time ago, you shouldn't be recommending it.

Comment: @DavidG you are indeed right, I've modified it to `SqlFunctions` for both

Comment: but when i have difference in seconds then i am getting 0.For Eg in the case of this datetime(2016-06-29 15:52:32.360,2016-06-29 15:52:36.970).So when i have difference in seconds i would like to know that second.likewise if difference is of minutes then i would like to know that minutes in the format of Hour:Minutes:seconds

Comment: @Learning your question implied you wanted the hours (because of the `.TotalHours` you wrote). Change the `"hour"``DateDiff("hour")` to the mininum you want (you can have `second`, `millisecond`, `microsecond` and `nanosecond`). You can divide that by 1000000, 1000, 60, etc, later to get the unit you want (or just convert to a `TimeSpan` afterwards if you need to output it in any format)

Comment: Sorry i have updated my question with input and expected output

Comment: @DavidG :Please see that my question is now different as i have updated it with input and expected output

Comment: @Learning If you have changed your question so fundamentally, then you should write a new one. Editing it like that is not acceptable as it wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @Learning I've updated my answer, but you need to make up your mind before asking a question, and include all the relevant data